Possible Combinations of Ferry Trips
I was visiting a seaside town this weekend where there was a ferry service and had the following question:

Suppose the ferry starts at 5 AM each morning and it takes 15 minutes to reach Point B - then leaves immediately, takes 15 minutes to reach Point A and again leave immediately)
The ferry runs every 30 minutes until 12 AM (i.e. leaves point A at 5 am,
The ferry has a capacity of 100 people each time
The ferry goes from Point A to Point B (nobody lives at Point B)
Today, $n$ people will use the ferry (each person can go from (a-b, b-a) for a maximum of $c$ times each day a minimum of 1 time)
At the end of the day, there is a risk that some people might get stranded overnight at Point B

Question: How many possible outcomes could have taken place over the day? I.e. Combnination_i = (Trip 1 $x$ people from a-b, Trip 2 $y$ people from b-a, Trip 3 $w$ people from a-b, etc etc ... at the end of the day, $z$ people are stranded etc)
Here is my try:
Idea 1 : Combinatorics:
$$x_i = \text{number of people on the i-th trip (i = 1, 2, ..., 38)}$$
$$z = \text{number of people stranded at Point B at the end of the day}$$
Constraints:
a) Capacity constraint for each trip:
$$0 \leq x_i \leq 100 \text{ for } i = 1, 2, ..., 38$$
Total number of ferry uses:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{38} x_i \leq n \times c$$
Stranded people constraint:
$$z = \sum_{i \text{ odd}} x_i - \sum_{i \text{ even}} x_i$$
$$0 \leq z \leq n$$
Formulation:
Count {$(x_1, x_2, ..., x_{38}, z)$} such that:
$$0 \leq x_i \leq 100 \text{ for } i = 1, 2, ..., 38$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{38} x_i \leq n \times c$$
$$z = \sum_{i \text{ odd}} x_i - \sum_{i \text{ even}} x_i$$
$$0 \leq z \leq n$$
$$x_i, z \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } i$$
Idea 2: Generating Function:
$$G(x, y) = \prod_{i=1}^{19} \left(\sum_{j=0}^{100} x^j\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^{100} y^k\right)$$
$x$ represents a person traveling from A to B, and $y$ represents a person traveling from B to A.
$$\sum_{j=0}^{100} x^j$$ represents the possibilities for an A to B trip (0 to 100 people).
$$\sum_{k=0}^{100} y^k$$ represents the possibilities for a B to A trip (0 to 100 people).
$$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{100} x^j\right) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^{100}$$
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{100} y^k\right) = 1 + y + y^2 + ... + y^{100}$$
The way I see it, coefficient of $x^a y^b$ in the expanded $G(x,y)$ represents the number of ways to have $a$ people travel from A to B and $b$ people travel from B to A over the entire day.
From here I am stuck. I tried to play around with this:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{100} x^j = \frac{1-x^{101}}{1-x}$$
$$G(x, y) = \left(\frac{1-x^{101}}{1-x}\right)^{19} \left(\frac{1-y^{101}}{1-y}\right)^{19}$$
Constraints in terms of generating function:

The coefficient of $x^a y^b$ where $0 \leq a-b \leq n$ represents valid outcomes.
$a+b \leq n \times c$ to satisfy the total trip constraint.

Can someone please help me think of ways to solve this
